# What does a joint pmf being uniform over a dotted area mean?

Tags: probability, statistics

In class, the tabular form used in our examples all had numerical values to them like the one shown:
[image]

but the assignment given to us doesn't have any numbers at all. It just says that the joint pmf is uniform over the dotted area and I have no idea what that means. Can someone explain it in an easy way to understand for a beginner stat student like me? Thanks.
I posted the image of the problem below.
[image]

Comment: "Uniform" just means that each point is equally likely.

Answer (score 1):

A uniform discrete distribution is one where the probability mass of each point in the support is equal to a constant.  Since there are 21 points in that support, the joint probability mass function is:

$$p_{\small X,Y}(x,y)=\tfrac 1{21}\mathbf 1_{\langle x,y\rangle\in{\Bbb N_0}^2,~x+y\leqslant 5}$$